# SSRS Report Builder not showing milliseconds

Tags: date, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

I have a date/time column in my report that is not showing as the following

mm/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ss am/pm

However, the milliseconds are getting shaved off when it is coming in from the database.  Is this a default of Report Builder to round and not show the milliseconds?

I need the milliseconds to be shown in the report if anyone has dealt with this before any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the milliseconds are truncated by default.

You would need to FORMAT the field with the little known **fff** for the milliseconds. You would also need to use **tt** for the AM or PM.

You can use the **FORMAT** function to format it:

```
=FORMAT(NOW(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")
```

Or you can use the FORMAT property of the text box.

[image]

I prefer to use the property when possible because it exports to Excel better (correctly?).

I am using Visual Studio 2012 so your Report Builder interface may look a little different.